# Compile scala files from a sbt plugin

Tags: scala, plugins, compiler-construction, sbt

I am developing a sbt plugin. In this plugin I generate some new scala sources packaged in a sbt project. Then I need to compile these new files programaticaly so that I could add the generated class in my classLoader.

I do not find any way to compile programaticaly sources from a given sbt project path (and eventually from a classLoader) in the sbt API, something as simple as the sbt command (*sbt compile*) line would be very convenient, something like:

```
XXX.compile(path/to/sbt/project)
```

Thanks

Comment: For now, the better option I found is to use : `sys.process.Process( Seq( "sbt", "compile" ),path) !!`, but I guess we can use an internal command of sbt to achieve this !

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you have a look at [sbt-boilerplate](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-boilerplate) which is an sbt plugin that generates code, works well and is really simple.

Here's a link to [the file that you probably want to take a look at](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-boilerplate/blob/master/src/main/scala/spray/boilerplate/BoilerplatePlugin.scala)